# How can I get first entry from a view using LotusNotes formula?

Tags: view, lotus-notes, formula

I have a view containing 2 columns: Name and Phone. The view name is vwOrder. Using Lotus @Formulas, how can I get the first entry ( first value for Phone ) that exists in this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @DbColumn to get a list of values of the Phone column.

```
Phones := @DbColumn("";"":"DB.NSF";"vwOrder";2)
```

Then just get the first value of that list

```
Firstphone := Phones[1]
```

Comment: In my case, a name can have more than one phones. But I want to display only one phone, not all of them for that name.

Comment: Use @Subset to get the value you want out of the list, e.g. the first one.
Perhaps you should take an evening or a weekend to actually read through the help file, for the formula language. That way you get an idea of what functions you have available. Then you refer to the help when you write your code.
I would also suggest to look at Lotusscript, there are many things you can do better and easier using Lotusscript.

Comment: @Subset is a fine way to go, but the indexer will work too in versions 6.0 and higher.